# CodeIgniter can't reference image folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I may have just been staring at my screen for too long today, I'm banging my head against the wall on this.

I want to search a folder (given by a variable) for any image file and display it.

this is what I have

```
      $files = glob('../Images/' . $row->id . '/*');
      natcasesort($files);
      foreach($files as $file) {
         echo '<img src="' . $file . '" />';
      }
```

It thinks the path of the image is:
http://testwebsites.com/ci/index.php/hw/id/Images/2/2.jpg

When the real path should be: http://testwebsites.com/ci/Images/2/2.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following code

```
       $files = glob('../ci/Images/' . $row->id . '/*');
        natcasesort($files);
        foreach($files as $file) {
           echo '<center><img src="../../../Images/' . $row->id . '/' . basename($file) . '" class="img-rounded" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 250px;"/></center>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code igniter runs from the basedirectory CI/index.php so all images should be referenced thinking you are working from CI/ folder and not CI/application/controllers/ directory.

so, what you should do is:

```
$files = glob('Images/' . $row->id . '/*');
  natcasesort($files);
  foreach($files as $file) {
     echo '<img src="' . $file . '" />';
  }
```

Comment: My Images folder is CI/Images and my index is CI/Index.php, they're not in the controller folder. That change still gives http://testwebsites.com/ci/index.php/hw/id/Images/2/2.jpg

Comment: @AndrewWilson You are referring to your full path. There is no path beyond a "file" (index.php). You should use `base_url()` like GautamD3164 stated, or use `$_SERVER` to figure out your absolute path and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$files = echo base_url()."/Images/".$row['id']."/*";
```

and also you can try like

```
$dir_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Images";
$files1 = scandir($dir_path);
```

Comment: Note that this requires you to load the `url`-helper (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: That just errors out (blanks out everything after that code segment), I think I need glob incase there are multiple files in that folder

Comment: Shouldn't it just be: `$files = glob(base_url().'Images/' . $row->id . '/*');` ?

Comment: May be it also work and also if you see my edit the second ans will give better soultion I think

Comment: Allendar, glob can't use external hyperlinks so base_url won't work

Comment: GautamD3164 the first suggestion doesn't work, the 2nd direction also isn't working :\

Comment: 2nd will work and I have done with it even.....dont forgot to give full path with it like...$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/my_Proj_folder/Images";...it shold work...in my case if I echo it it will print like "var/www/codeigniter/Images/"

Comment: I can get the absolute path from that, but how do i display an image through php with an absolute path?

Comment: CI links it to this if i use absolute path http://testwebsites.com/var/www/testwebsites.com/html/ci/Images/1/1.JPG

Comment: Print the $files1 fro second result you can get may be..??